# Why does my ship look like it's going backwards instead of fowards?

Tags: unity, movement, transformation, fbx

I'm making an *Asteroids*-clone based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=InVxO58tFBM&list=PL57F280203FBFE605&index=5). I'm stuck on the 5th part of the tutorial.

For some reason my ship is going backwards instead of forward or it looks like its going forward, but in the tutorial the ship gos toward the asteroid.
In the debug log, the z axis increments in a positive value. so I assume it is going forward but for some reason the ship it self doesnt go towards the asteroid like it does in the tutorial. The ship itself is an fbx export from Maya 2014.

Here's an annotated screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

<sup>[Full size version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txnsS.png)</sup>

It's probably something really stupid, but I just can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: although the blue z arrow does point to the asteroid now its still does the same thing even if i rotate the ship around but now the values are negative in the debug loghttp://postimg.org/image/ua122f1c3/full/  @Ideae

Comment: how is this question off topic as i do present a concise selection of code(in the picture) and context. i even debugged it myself and there appeared to be nothing wrong. i even tried some things myself and still had a problem which is why i am asking this question.plus its not that much code to look at so i dont see what the problem with this question is and yes i read the threads about debugging questions and such @JoshPetrie

Answer (score 0):

The code is good and Unity it's working correctly (look at the arrows on the screenshot, they're pointing in the right direction). As far as the screenshot helps me to debug, you just need to rotate the object and go torwards th

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, his positive z direction is equivalent to your negative z direction.

Notice in the top right corner of the scene view, you have an axis indicator to tell you where the camera is currently facing (it says Persp, and shows x, y and z). Also notice how in the tutorial, his axis is aligned in the opposite z direction than yours. If you click the z part of it, the camera will flip around, giving the the correct view that you want to be editing from. You'll have to turn your ship around and move the asteroid over to the over side of your ship in order to be in sync with the tutorial's setup.

Comment: I cannot comment on your answer, because I lack the 50 rep needed. Anyways, I think now that you have made the change the scene, you'll need to rotate your ship accordingly. I couldn't see it clearly in the updated picture you posted in your comment.

Comment: well I did rotate it unity and it still went in the opposite the direction I even rotated the object in maya and then Re-exported it and it still gos backwards instead of forward although now the z arrow is pointing towards the asteroids :P